# Is there a good alternative for "versions" in the following context?

Tags: word-request

I wonder if there is a good alternative for "versions" in the following context. I looked up the synonyms (variant, adaptation, rendering, etc.), but I thought they were not that much suitable in my context.

> Andersen's fairy tale was different from older **versions** of the
> story.

Comment: _Versions_ would be the normal word in this context - _variant_ is possible too.

Comment: @KateBunting, Are "versions" and "variants" interchangeable here?

Comment: Have you some objection to using _version_? As I said, I consider it to be the usual word with reference to traditional stories/songs., but _variants_ (slightly different versions) could be used with a similar meaning (as in the Vaughan Williams composition [Five Variants of 'Dives and Lazarus'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Variants_of_Dives_and_Lazarus)

Comment: @KateBunting,  I asked for an alternative word because I wanted to avoid repetition. Actually, I've used the word "version" in preceding lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

> variations

Or maybe you are better looking at synonyms of "recite", for example:

> tellings, recountings, narrations, recitations, interpretations.

However, I think *versions* already sounds suitable.